# Power of a square root of a logarithm

Tags: limits, logarithms, radicals, fractions

I'll be frank. This is homework. And I'm not actually asking for the answer. Just for... something.

$$ \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{n^a}{2^{\sqrt{\ln n}}}, a \in \mathbf{N}, a > 1$$

The point is to apply a limit and get to either a constant, zero or infinity, when $n$ gets close to infinity, obviously. It seems that I need to move the $n$ in the denominator to the numerator, but it's just dug in so *deep*. This is a fraction, so the only operation I can do on both sides is multiplication and there are no common factors on both sides. I can do a Lhopital rule, but deriving the denominator will *still* get me a variation of the original value.

Basically, is there any hint on how I can get rid of the $2$ and just reach the square root of the natural logarithm directly? Then, things are obviously much easier. Or change the denominator so that the derivation produces something *useful*?

Again, I'm not looking for the solution, just for a starting point. I tried many things and I never seem to be getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want only a **hint**:

You may set $n=e^{t^2}$ and now consider the new expression for $t \to +\infty$.

Comment: How did you know to do that?

Comment: @eje211 : In order to get rid of the logarithm, I need $e^{something}$. To get rid of the root, that something should be a square.

Comment: Oh, because then, I have an $e$ where my $n$ was, but also a variable and a square! I never would have thought of changing the variable!

Comment: @eje211 : This trick is quite often useful. So, good to keep this in mind. Using this trick, you can often simplify seemingly ugly expressions into much nicer ones.

Comment: This is amazing! You absolutely did not give me the answer and I may still have gotten in wrong. (This is a *good* thing.) I'd much rather have learned something I can reuse (if I think of it) than copy and paste something I don't understand. It's so simple in retrospect! I'm getting back to studying something that needs math after a break without it. It's so cool, and it really does get an undeserved reputation as not being a creative skill.

Comment: @eje211 : If you look around here on this platform, you will see that "intuiting" a nice substitution can have a tremendous simplifying character to solving a problem. Just check out some answers to limits, integrals or inequalities. To somehow have a good gut feeling which substitution may work, I find this definitely also to be a creative process. Of course, not always but quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Write $k=\sqrt{\ln n}$. We have $k\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$ and $n=e^{k^2}$.
$$\frac{n^a}{2^{\sqrt{\ln n}}}=\frac{e^{ak^2}}{2^k}$$
Now something should be clear.